# HttpContext.Current.Request resulting in null object reference in Outer C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm using to get web address from the code itself. But the code where I'm trying to generate web url is in outer C# class.

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host +
                        (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port);
```

`The error above line giving is : Object reference not set to an Instance of an Object`
The class is under Helpers folder of Solution. As far as I can grasp, it has do something about the location of class as if the above code would have been in any Controller, then the web url would have resulted.

**UPDATED**

From **Global.asax** file in the Application_Start method I'm calling the above stated class.

Comment: How do you call the code in there? Can you show more context?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have updated my Ques

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You probably should change this to "how do I do X" because building a URL at application startup happens outside of any context where there is a *useful* URL to use. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

`Request` object is NOT available for `Application_Start` event

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)
means that this event does not represent `Http` events.

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

And what's represented by `HttpApplication` you can check via this link [HttpApplication Class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `Application_Start` event is raised without a request attached to it. The request object is not available yet. (It can be raised when the application is pre-loaded for example. In such cases there is simply no request yet.)

You might use the `Begin_Request` event and check if it is the first time in that session.